# Set Home Location - DJI Android Mobile SDK

Tags: java, android, location, dji-sdk

I've succeeded to add a Marker on Google Maps by using the public void **onMapClick(LatLng point).**

I stored the value of " point " into a **private LatLng mLatLngHOME** = point; ( which will be used for the method **initFlightController()** to set Home location).

```
private void initFlightController() {

    if (isFlightControllerSupported()) {
        mFlightController = ((Aircraft) DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct()).getFlightController();
        mFlightController.setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(FlightControllerState djiFlightControllerCurrentState) {

                    djiFlightControllerCurrentState.setHomeLocation(new LocationCoordinate2D(mLatLngHOME.latitude, mLatLngHOME.longitude));
            }
        });
    }
}

private boolean isFlightControllerSupported() {
    return DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct() != null &&
            DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct() instanceof Aircraft &&
            ((Aircraft) DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct()).getFlightController() != null;
}
```

Using a DJI Demo Application (*DJIDemoApplication.java* & *MApplication.java*), I created a **Broadcast Receiver** in the *MainActivity.java*.

In the Broadcast, I call a method **updateFlightController()** where I'm displaying some Toast message :

```
private void updateFlightController() {

    if (isFlightControllerSupported()) {
        mFlightController = ((Aircraft) DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct()).getFlightController();
        mFlightController.setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(FlightControllerState djiFlightControllerCurrentState) {

                    // TEST
                    showToast("mLatLngHOME = " + mLatLngHOME);
                    showToast("Latitude / Longitude = " + mLatLngHOME.latitude + " / " + mLatLngHOME.longitude);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The issue is, they display **mLatLngHOME = null** and **Latitude / Longitude = NaN / NaN**.

> As if in the **updateFlightController()** method, it stays into a loop
>   and keep some old values.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with DJI's SDK since the class and points you are using do not originate with DJI's products.

Answer (score 0):

The `mLatLngHOME` variable is never updated in the `onUpdate()` method of the FlightController's `setStateCallback` , so it's definitely keep the old values. Please check the code below for reference:

```
 if (mFlightController != null) {
        mFlightController.setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(FlightControllerState djiFlightControllerCurrentState) {
                droneLocationLat = djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getAircraftLocation().getLatitude();
                droneLocationLng = djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getAircraftLocation().getLongitude();
                updateDroneLocation();
            }
        });
    }
```

For more details of using DJIFlightController, you can check this tutorial: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/GSDemo-Google-Map.html#locating-aircraft-on-google-map

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It means It can not get the location and I faced with it when I was using DJI Assistant 2 for a simulation drone flight in my room.

To solve it just **set a location** for your drone in the simulator and also **turn off the RTK** if your drone has it.

By doing this your problem will be solved.